# Win11: Is there any way to darken or change the color of the context menu's selected item?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11, context-menu

See this screenshot:

[image: Context Menu]

I can barely see what's selected in the right-click menu. I'm on Windows 11 Pro 22H2 Build 22621.1.

Is there any way to change the highlight color?

Also, I can't stand that they nullified the ability to bring back the ribbon in the insiders build. I absolutely hate having to open a menu and then click to create a new folder. Why couldn't MS add a new folder button on the main navigation bar of explorer?

I'm probably going to revert back to Windows 10, but holding out hope that these issues can be solved somehow.

Any tips / tricks / tools / etc., that can accomplish what I'm looking for?

Could really use some help.

Comment: There's likely an ARGB or RGBA hex value in the Registry that controls it's color _(it may use the same key Win10 uses, which I can post later in a comment since I'm not on a PC)_. If it does use a Registry key, and you want to use the same color with less transparency, modify the A[lpha] value to have a higher value [`00` (0) fully transparent - `FF` (255) fully opaque]

Comment: @JW0914 that would be awesome if you could post the key when you are back at a PC. Right now I'm digging through the theme with msstyleeditor and I'm completely overwhelmed. I think it might be overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Complain loudly in the Insider Feedback Forum.  Someone at Microsoft thinks that white text on a white background is cool. Lack of Context and more menus is also problematic.  I suggest you enter feedback

Comment: @John I suppose I'll do just that! I think their UI/UX team is on drugs.

Comment: Yes I think so. The insider build does not even adhere to Personalization Accent Colors.

Comment: @Jay Since Microsoft largely kept in place highlighting specified in the Registry from Win8 to Win10 _(most Registry theme colors were depreciated in Win10 even though they still exist in the Registry - e.g. changing them does nothing)_, it's likely they're still used in Win11 and not apart of the theme/msstyle since modifying the msstyle files corrupts them as they're not intended to be user modified _(e.g. if theme colors can be customized through Settings, it's definitely not apart of msstyle files)_

Comment: @John Unsure if Stardock has released [WindowBlinds](https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) for Win11 yet, but if wanting a truly customized UI, that's the way to go _(it allows changing colors, icons, symbols, lines, etc. - for example, you can take any icon, open it in a Photoshop app and replace parts of it pixel by pixel to change it's color, transparency, etc.)_ For Windows 8 and 10, I found a pre-built theme I liked them used its theme editor [Skin Studio] to granularly customize every part of the UI

Comment: I do not know for this particular issue, but in the large Microsoft has reduced and hampered things that Software Vendor can do by registry changes.

Comment: @John Specific to Stardock WindowsBlinds, it doesn't use the Registry to make changes and does something with the Windows Shell, but I'm unsure what exactly. SkinStudio is bundled with it and both allow changing most parts of the UI, from horizontal and vertical lines within Explorer, to the close, minimize, maximize, and other buttons, and almost every other granular component of the UI. It lost some features beginning with Win10 due to the integration of Windows Apps changing how the OS UI is built and implemented _(this is why many of the Registry color keys are ineffective in Win10+)_

Comment: @Jay Check `Hilight` in `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors` and `HKCU\Control Panel\Colors`, as well as `MenuBar` in the latter, with all values in both being numerical `RRR GGG BBB` [`0` - `255`] _(there's another set of color keys in ARGB or RGBA hex value within either `HKCU` or `HKLM`, but IIRC they're the keys for the theme colors - I don't recall at the moment the exact location, but will reply when I've found it)_